# Microsoft pubCenter ads not showing in my WP8 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, ads

I can't get Microsoft pubCenter ads to work in my Windows Phone 8 App.
When I run my app I only see white space instead of the ad
Changing to test values doesn't seem to show an ad neither
Can you help me? Thanks in advance

That's what I see in my pubCenter account
[image: a]

That's my XAML and my app's references
[image: b]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this It Should Work fine

Xaml:

```
xmlns:UI="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI;assembly=Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI"

<UI:AdControl ApplicationId="test_client" AdUnitId="Image480_80" Height="80" Width="480" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ErrorOccurred="AdControl_ErrorOccurred"/>
```

The following ID_CAP capabilities must be included in the manifest of the advertising-enabled app.
ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER

ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO

ID_CAP_NETWORKING

ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER

ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT

Comment: thanks, I forgot to select "ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO", i probably selected "ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_AUDIO" (which was active) by mistake instead of the right one

Answer (score 0):

It takes PubCenter a couple of days to populate ads for a new App. To see how the ads look, use the default ad in debug mode. Once PubCenter has seeded Bing's ad delivery system, you'll start seeing ads in App.

```
#if DEBUG
        return new AdControl()
        {
            AdUnitId = "Image480_80",
            ApplicationId = "test_client",
            Height = 80,
            IsAutoCollapseEnabled = autocollapse,
            IsAutoRefreshEnabled = true,
            Width = 480,
        };
#endif
```

Comment: Even if i use those test parameters, it doesn't show anything on my app :(

Comment: @user3316583 Do you see anything? Disable autocollapse - make sure the control is visible at all.

Comment: Even if I put the code of the official walkthrough in a blank app, it doesn't show me anything at runtime. In the XAML designer I see a black box. Autocollapse is disabled.

Comment: @user3316583 not sure what the issue is then, still could be related to the fact that BingAds hasn't indexed you yet. After a day or so, if it's still not working, I'd get worried.

Comment: i don't even see test ads (with "Image480_80" and "test_client" so I think there's a big problem here. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help, i was looking into Google Ads which I already use for my little Android app, but when I try to import the dll it says my versione of Visual Studio is unsupported (I run 2012 update 4). It seems like I got no luck with mobile advertising.

Comment: @user3316583 One more thought: do you have App permissions set up correctly to display ads? I believe you need networking and a couple of other CAPS enabled.